# Customize forms Symfony

Tags: php, html, forms, symfony

I'm trying to customize my forms. I have been using 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html
as reference for theme/form customization, but I'm not quite grasping the concept.

**What I currently have**
RegistrationForm.php

```
  class UserRegistrationForm extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                ->add('email', EmailType::class)
                ->add('username', TextType::class)
                ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, ['type' => PasswordType::class])
                ->add('IHaveReadAndAcceptTheTermsOfService', CheckboxType::class, array(
            'mapped' => false,
            'constraints' => new IsTrue(),));


        }

        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults([
                'data_class' => User::class,
                'validation_groups' => ['Default', 'Registration']
            ]);
        }
```

**Register.html.twig**

```
   {% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h1>Register!</h1>

                {{ form_start(form, {'attr':{'class':'boxsize'}}) }}
                {{ form_row(form.username) }}
                {{ form_row(form.email)}}
                {{ form_row(form.plainPassword.first, {
                    'label': 'Password'
                }) }}

                {{ form_row(form.plainPassword.second, {
                    'label': 'Repeat Password'
                }) }}
                <a href="https://termsfeed.com/terms-servicee">Terms of service</a>
                {{ form_row(form.IHaveReadAndAcceptTheTermsOfService) }}

                <a href="web/">cancel</a>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" formnovalidate>
                    Register
                </button>

                <br></br>

                <p><a href="https://termsfeed.com/privacy">Privacy Policy</a>


                {{ form_end(form) }}

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

In CSS

```
.boxsize {
    width: 200px;
}
```

**What I am trying to do.**

Make this boxsize the default size when I create a form. As it stands I would have to use class:boxsize for each form I create.

Comment: What's wrong with your approach? If you don't want to use symfony forms, you could use something like jQuery in a common base twig file so that it applies the class to all forms. Within a jQuery block use `$('form').addClass('boxsize');`

Comment: If you want a default width for every form without setting `class:boxsize` each time, then set a CSS rule for `form` instead of `.boxsize`. I cannot see what's the issue.